# How to send an integer (4 bytes) via networkStream in C#?

Tags: c#, client-server, networkstream

I'm new at programming and I'm creating server to work with a device. I have this problem for days and not able to find solution.

The task is: After the server receives data, the server must report to the device the number of data received as integer (four bytes). If sent data number and reported by server doesn’t match, device resends sent data.

```
if (checkedCrc == false){
   int dataEl = -1;
   byte[] buffAnswer = BitConverter.GetBytes(dataEl);
   await networkStream.WriteAsync(buffAnswer, 0, 4);
   Log.Debug("Sent: " + dataEl);
}
```

However, even if I'm sending wrong data number (-1) to the device, I'm, not getting data resend (meaning that I'm sending the data in wrong way). Where could the problem be?

Comment: There are a lot of possible problems, but what about the protocol? How does the device expect the number to be sent? As bytes? If so, 32 bit , 64 bit? big endian? little endian? Any "end-of-message" code? As ascii-string? string with cr/lf? ...

Comment: Before sending and receiving anything, have you established a connection from both sides (client and server), it would help to see the whole code where you are creating/connecting the Sockets/TcpListener/TcpClients, getting the networkstream, the other end of the device where it is reading from the networkstream... This snippet code you have posted doesnt provide enough information.

Comment: Not to mention that instead of 4 bytes you should be sending and receiving buffAnswer.Length, and both the receiver and send should have the same amount, so you want to make sure that int is the same amount of bytes for both devices.

Comment: In protocol it's written that as integer (four bytes).

Comment: So you already successfully receive some data from device, then respond with length of data as described in your question code and after that you receive no more data from device?

Comment: @Evk Yes. I successfully get data from the device, but I'm, not able to tell the device how many elements I've got (it's not resending data even if I'm telling him wrong number of data received).

Comment: @ArmanPapikyan I uploaded the whole code

Comment: You mention that even if you respond with -1, the client doesn't resend the data. Wouldn't it make more sense for the client to also resend data when it receives an invalid response from the server? Does the client log anything?

Comment: @C.Evenhuis If it receives invalid response the client would resend data. The problem, that I'm making a mistake somewhere and device probably does not understand, that I've sent the data so it's not resending it.

Comment: I'd say that a response the client "does not understand" is exactly the same as a client "receiving an invalid response", so if I were in your position I'd examine what the client currently receives. But everyone has their own approach of course.